# Lista de videos com link para carrega outro video sem refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.

Quero criar uma lista de videos na qual eu terei um vídeo principal (quadro maior) e uma sequencia em lista com miniatura dos outros.
Porém, nesta lista de miniaturar deverá ter um link que faça com que ele carregue no quadro do vídeo principal.

Algo como:

```css
.video {
  background: #005299;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
}

.miniatura {
  background: #0091ea;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="video">
    <embed width="480" height="320" src="https://video.com/video.mp4">
  </li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a href="#">VIDEO 1</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a href="#">VIDEO 2</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a href="#">VIDEO 3</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a href="#">VIDEO 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bom, agora nessa estrutura teria que receber um script javascript ou jquery para fazer com que os links alterem a url do **< embed >** sem atualizar a pagina, só que não faço ideia de como fazer isso.

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia ai?

Answer (score -1):

**Jquery**

**biblioteca**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lista li a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (id=="v1"){
            $("#video").html('<embed width="480" height="320" src="https://video.com/video1.mp4">');
        }
        if (id=="v2"){
            $("#video").html('<embed width="480" height="320" src="https://video.com/video2.mp4">');
        }
        if (id=="v3"){
            $("#video").html('<embed width="480" height="320" src="https://video.com/video3.mp4">');
        }
        if (id=="v4"){
            $("#video").html('<embed width="480" height="320" src="https://video.com/video4.mp4">');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id='lista'>
  <li class="video">
   <div id="video"><embed width="480" height="320" src="tito.mp4"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a id="v1" href="#">VIDEO 1</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a id="v2" href="#">VIDEO 2</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a id="v3" href="#">VIDEO 3</a></li>
  <li class="miniatura"><a id="v4" href="#">VIDEO 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Opa, parece interessante, acabei de ver e vou testar, mas uma duvida antes. As <li> das miniaturas, pretendo puxar do banco de dados com PHP, while ou foreach. A passagem dos IDs funcionara?

Comment: Ai só vendo o PHP, while ou foreach, mas podes criar com algo como < ?php echo "id=v".$i ? >

Comment: eu uso um crud, "kkk"
$listar = listar('tabela', "WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $pageReturn[1], $pageReturn[2]");
    foreach ($listar as $video):?>
<!-- estrutuda -->
<?= $video->link ?>
<!-- estrutuda -->
    <? endforeach; ?>

Comment: xiiii, falou grego comigo, hahaha

Comment: kkk veja, **<?= $video->link ?>** esse é o echo que retorna o valor do link do vídeo puxado do DB (poderia ser qualquer outro valor como **<?= $video->titulo_video ?>** etc.). - Vou fazer outra resposta para explicar melhor.

Answer (score -1):

Basicamente minha estrutura php é gerada por esse código.

```html
<ul id='lista'>
  <li class="video">
    <div id="video">
      <embed width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SNKE_B__51E">
    </div>
  </li>
  <? $listar = listar('video', "WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
    foreach ($listar as $video):
?>

    <li class="miniatura">
      <a id="v1" href="<?= $video->link?>">VIDEO 1</a>
    </li>

    <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Ok, essa é a estrutura que pretendo fazer (basicamente já tenho), porém como faço para lançar o link de cada item desse loop na função jquery?

??? ->

```js
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lista li a').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if (id == "v1") {
                $("#video").html('<embed id="embed" width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5gDjYPSlnAE">');
            }
            if (id == "v2") {
                $("#video").html('<embed id="embed" width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLbLg2FVQ68">');
            }
            if (id == "v3") {
                $("#video").html('<embed id="embed" width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-KTIswXkBPw">');
            }
            if (id == "v4") {
                $("#video").html('<embed id="embed" width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MLi6OWFWYmc">');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: vc usou o campo para respostas, é melhor remover essa resposta e criar outra pergunta ou editar a sua pergunta lá em cima